# How to perfom PUT and DELETE operation in Restful API using express nodejs and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, asynchronous, mongoose

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS3h5.png)

```js
//Routes.js

module.exports = function(app){
var todolist = require('../controllers/todolistcontroller');

//Defining the routes

app.route('/tasks')
.get(todolist.list_all_tasks)
.post(todolist.create_a_newtask);

app.route('/tasks/taskId')
.get(todolist.read_a_task)
.put(todolist.update_a_task)
.delete(todolist.delete_a_task);
};
```

```js
//Controller.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Task = mongoose.model('Tasks');

exports.list_all_tasks = function(req,res){
    Task.find({},function(err,task){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json(task);
    });
};

exports.create_a_newtask = function(req,res){
    var newTask = new Task(req.body);
    newTask.save(function(err,task){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json(task);
    });
};

exports.read_a_task = function(req,res){
    Task.findById(req.params.taskId,function(err,task){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json(task);
    });
};

exports.update_a_task = function(req,res){
    Task.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.taskId},req.body,{new : true},function(err,task){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json(task);
    });
};

exports.delete_a_task = function(req,res){
    Task.remove({_id:req.params.taskId},function(err,task){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json({message:'Task deleted'});
    });
};
```

Written simple CRUD operation using RESTful Api with `express.js` framework in `nodejs` and `mongoose`. Tested with POSTMAN, received the entire database in response & posting new data works fine. However, `PUT` & `DELETE` methods are not working. Not able to figure out the bug.

Help me out to find the bug, thanks in advance.

Here's My code

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Task = mongoose.model('Tasks');

exports.list_all_tasks = function(req,res){
    Task.find({},function(err,task){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json(task);
    });
};

exports.create_a_newtask = function(req,res){
    var newTask = new Task(req.body);
    newTask.save(function(err,task){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json(task);
    });
};

exports.read_a_task = function(req,res){
    Task.findById(req.params.taskId,function(err,task){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json(task);
    });
};

exports.update_a_task = function(req,res){
    Task.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.taskId},req.body,{new : true},function(err,task){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json(task);
    });
};

exports.delete_a_task = function(req,res){
    Task.remove({_id:req.params.taskId},function(err,task){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json({message:'Task deleted'});
    });
};
```

Comment: Share your routes

Comment: share your controller.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: when I'm performing delete & update operation using POSTMAN                             I'm getting **Cannot DELETE /tasks/5b9622550358d22d88b19d4a** @weirdpanda

Comment: What error is it showing?